# SOLVED:How to add liquid snippet file of custom app on its installation?

Tags: shopify

I am trying to place liquid file with other files on my Shopify store WHEN I install my custom app.
I have an application which is working successfully after installation in my store

Problem: I have manually included  snippet of my application
I want the snippet in to be a liquid file which gets place in store theme files whenever someone installs my application

Comment: you need to check the assets endpoint into REST API, which may help you in this case.

Comment: I have checked them but they offer only delete,retrieve all,retrieve by id and update
So, how i would create a new liquid file every time user installs app

Comment: Might be this ones give you some idea about next steps: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/PUT-new-file-under-Sections/td-p/775501

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by reference given in Onkar's  first comment, I Used assets rest api to create file upon app's installation.